# Forma correta de checagem de NULL do Scala no Java

Tags: java, scala

Primeiramente, quero falar que sou totalmente leigo em Scala. Não sei quase nada além do básico da linguagem. Sabendo disso, vamos a minha dúvida.

Estou em um projeto onde há bibliotecas desenvolvidas em Scala. Essas bibliotecas foram empacotadas em JAR's e eu importo no projeto Java. Até aí tudo bem. Eu não tenho acesso aos fontes dessas bibliotecas em Scala.

O que acontece é que as vezes eu preciso comparar `null`. No Java isso é de uma forma e pelo jeito no Scala parece ser de outra forma.

Vamos a um exemplo prático para ilustrar meu problema. Vamos supor que minha lib em escala retorna um objeto `Usuario`:

```
Usuario user = usuarioService.getUsuario(usuarioID);
System.out.println(usuario.nome().get());
System.out.println(usuario.email().get());
```

No exemplo acima estou usando a lib feita em Scala e buscando informações de um Usuario. Tudo é objeto Scala, da lib em Scala.

Agora, eu quero verificar se o atributo `nome`, por exemplo é `nulo` ou não. Eu vi duas formas. Uma que acredito ser *Java Way* e outra *Scala Way*.

**Java Way**

```
final scala.Option<String> None = scala.Option.apply(null);
Usuario user = usuarioService.getUsuario(usuarioID);
if (!user.nome().equals(None)) {
    System.out.println(usuario.nome().get());
}
```

**Scala Way**

```
Usuario user = usuarioService.getUsuario(usuarioID);
if (user.nome().nonEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(usuario.nome().get());
}
```

Agora a pergunta, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso quando se está desenvolvendo em Java e usando libs feitas em Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 traz uma uma nova [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) para evitar verbosidade e excessivo "checks" a `null` e por consequência, NPE indesejados através de métodos que indicam a falta de um possível valor de retorno.

Esse é o [mesmo proposito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698391/when-to-use-option) do [Scala.option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Option).

No java 8 o nome da API é [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Aplicando ao seu código teríamos :

**Primeiramente alteramos o retorno de** `usuarioService.getUsuario.getUsuario` adicionando o [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

```
public Optional<Usuario> getUsuario(String usuarioID) {
```

**Agora é so utilizar da API para checar a existencia de um retorno**:

```
Optional <Usuario> user = usuarioService.getUsuario(usuarioID);
if (user.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(user.get().nome().get());
}
```

Segue uma visão mais aprofundada no documento da Oracle:
[Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Comment: Achei bem interessante o Optional! Fiz algumas experiências aqui e é be legal mesmo. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Exato Reginaldo, essa maneira é muito interessante e traz um smell funcional pra linguagem. Interessantemente, Optional em Java tb é um Monad.  http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#monad-laws